# My match function is taking too long (3 hours!!), need another recommendation

Tags: excel, vba

As the title says, match function taking too long. One spreadsheet is 100,000 rows long and it has a bunch of securities that i need to make sure are on another spreadsheet which has 800,000 rows. Below is the code:

FYI i am average in code building so i am pretty rudimentary in terms of laying out my arguments.

```
 Option Explicit
 'a lot of dims
 StartTime = Timer

 Set ShVar = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("in1")


With wnewwqr
    Set OutShVar = wnewwqr.Worksheets("First Sheet")
    Set RngConcat = OutShVar.Range("B:B")
    Set RngConcatISIN = OutShVar.Range("A:A")
    Set OutShVar1 = wnewwqr.Worksheets("Second Sheet")
    Set RngConcat1 = OutShVar1.Range("B:B")
    Set RngConcatISIN1 = OutShVar1.Range("A:A")
End With

With ShVar
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
 End With

 For i = 2 To lastrow
     With ShVar

         If .Range("O" & i).Value = "" Then     
             .Range("P" & i & ":Q" & i).Value = "No Security"   'Checking for no securities
         Else
             If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Range("O" & i).Value, RngConcat, 0)) Then
                 .Range("P" & i).Value = "US"     ' writing US when it finds a US security in the confidential workbook
             Else
                 .Range("P" & i).Value = "Not a US Security"
             End If
         End If
         If .Range("P" & i).Value = "Not a US Security" Then
             If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Range("O" & i).Value, RngConcat1, 0)) Then        'Only searching for securities if the first vlookup resulted in nothing and then it would go into the second sheet
                 .Range("Q" & i).Value = "US"
             Else
                 .Range("Q" & i).Value = .Range("P" & i).Value
             End If
         End If
     End With
 Next i



SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
'Notify user in seconds
MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Update:

I have turned everything to variant and now using find function but still not that fast as i would have hoped. Took 14 mins approx. to do a trial run of 2000 rows. And i have to do this on 90,000 rows

```
Option Explicit
Sub something
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim OutShVar As Worksheet
Dim ShVar As Worksheet
Dim WhatCell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim TaskID As Variant
Dim confidentialfp As String
Dim confidential As String
Dim wconfidential As Workbook
Dim x As Variant

Set ShVar = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("in1")

With ShVar
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
End With

 confidential = "confidential_2018-03-01 (Consolidated).xlsx"


Set wconfidential = Workbooks(confidential)

With wconfidential
Set OutShVar = .Worksheets("First Sheet")
End With

 With ShVar
 For i = 1 To lastrow
 TaskID = ShVar.Range("O" & i).Value
Set x = .Range("A" & i)
 Set WhatCell = OutShVar.Range("B:B").Find(TaskID, lookat:=xlWhole)
On Error Resume Next
x.Offset(0, 7).Value = WhatCell.Offset(0, 1)
Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Change everything to variant arrays and loop those not the ranges.  load another array with the output and post the results at one time.

Comment: Why are you looping twice through the same rows? Will, for example column `P` have a value of "Not a US Security" *before* you run the macro?

Comment: When i wrote that, i assumed, it has already written "Not a US security" before it goes onto the next part. Scott - i am looking arrays

Comment: It might help to outline the business rules for each set of 3 columns - it's not super-clear from the included code.

Comment: @ScottCraner i have changed everything to variant, see the update, still not that fast as i would have hoped. Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you're quite getting ScottCraner's point. What he's saying is you should read all of your reference values (ie the big list of securities) into a couple of arrays, and you should write your output values to another array. You'd then write the entire output array to the sheet in one command.

It might also be worth you converting your list of securities to a `Collection` as that has a very fast 'look-up' capability. There'd be ways of making this much faster, for example by sorting the securities, but you'd need to get into some mathematics for that.

In the example below, this skeleton code shows how it might be done. You should be aware that I didn't bother splitting the two securities lists into two collections, so you'd want to do that yourself if you needed it. I've also put all my test sheets on the same workbook, so adjust the worksheet qualifiers as needed:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RunMe()
    Dim securities As Collection
    Dim testSheet As Worksheet
    Dim testItems As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim exists As Boolean
    Dim output() As Variant

    'Read the first list of securities into the collection.
    PopulateColumnCollection _
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("First Sheet"), _
        "B", _
        securities

    'Read the second list of securities into the collection.
    'I've used the same collection in this example, you'll need
    'to create two if you want separate columns in your output.
    PopulateColumnCollection _
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Second Sheet"), _
        "B", _
        securities

    'Read the test items into an array.
    Set testSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("in1")
    With testSheet
        testItems = RangeTo2DArray(.Range( _
            .Cells(2, "O"), _
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp)))
    End With

    'Prepare your output array.
    'I've just used one column for output. If you want two then
    'you'll need to resize the second dimension.
    ReDim output(1 To UBound(testItems, 1), 1 To 1)

    'Populate the output array based on the presence of
    'a matching security.
    For i = 1 To UBound(testItems, 1)
        If IsEmpty(testItems(i, 1)) Then
            output(i, 1) = "No Security"
        Else
            exists = False: On Error Resume Next
            exists = securities(CStr(testItems(i, 1))): On Error GoTo 0
            output(i, 1) = IIf(exists, "US", "Not a US Security")
        End If
    Next

    'Write the output array to your sheet.
    testSheet.Cells(2, "P").Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output
End Sub

Private Function RangeTo2DArray(rng As Range) As Variant
'Helper function to read range values into an array.

    Dim v As Variant
    Dim arr(1 To 1, 1 To 1) As Variant

    v = rng.Value2
    If Not IsArray(v) Then
        arr(1, 1) = v
        RangeTo2DArray = arr
    Else
        RangeTo2DArray = v
    End If
End Function
Private Sub PopulateColumnCollection(ws As Worksheet, columnIndex As String, col As Collection)
'Helper sub to read a column of values into a collection.
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With ws
        Set rng = .Range( _
            .Cells(1, columnIndex), _
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnIndex).End(xlUp))
    End With
    v = RangeTo2DArray(rng)

    If col Is Nothing Then Set col = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next 'this avoids duplicates.
    For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        col.Add True, CStr(v(i, 1))
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Never used this method before. Let me try this and get back to you. Thank you so much for the assistance here

Comment: Good Lord, worked like a charm. I need to get to this level

Comment: That's good. Let us know how you feel about how long it takes. As I said, if you want to go faster - much faster - then you could sort all your securities' lists and revert to arrays.

Comment: 10 seconds and i modified it to my way. The speed is perfect to our requirements.

Comment: Hello Ambie, sorry to ask a question again on this one, do you know if i can add a vlookup on this statement:

Comment: output(i, 1) = IIf(exists, "US", "Not a US Security")

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I suggest you post another question and I, or someone else, can help you with that. Remember to have a go yourself first as people here much prefer working with something you've already tried.